# Как импортировать папку с приложением в другое приложение в django

Tags: python, django, python-import

Когда я пытаюсь импортировать папку с другим приложением и потом делаю миграции, мне выдаёт ошибку.

У меня есть 2 приложения (1 приложение - *orders*) (2 приложение - *products*).

Я пытаюсь в *orders.models* импортировать *models* из 2 приложения, в итоге выдаёт ошибку при миграции `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

**Структура проекта:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```
from ..products.models import Product
```

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, напишите [самоответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение! Мы импортируем sys и os и выходим из нашей папки в корневую папку проекта

`sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))`

после вы можем импортировать другие папки другого приложения, НО они будут подчёркиваться красным, НО ЭТО НЕ ОШИБКА, всё будет работать как надо –